# why pcl.dll not formed when i build by osdesign in wince 6.0 r2?

Tags: windows-ce

i have set the `sysgen_pcl = 1` and `sysgen_printing = 1`. i am able to see usb `usbprn.dll` but not `pcl.dll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the answer 
just make it caps i.e. `SYSGEN_PCL = 1` `SYSGEN_PRINTING = 1`

### :)